# Timestamps in Golang

Tags: go

Trying to get this approach to timestamps working in my application: https://gist.github.com/bsphere/8369aca6dde3e7b4392c#file-timestamp-go

Here it is:

```
package timestamp

import (
    "fmt"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Timestamp time.Time

func (t *Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    ts := time.Time(*t).Unix()
    stamp := fmt.Sprint(ts)

    return []byte(stamp), nil
}

func (t *Timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    ts, err := strconv.Atoi(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *t = Timestamp(time.Unix(int64(ts), 0))

    return nil
}

func (t Timestamp) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    if time.Time(*t).IsZero() {
        return nil, nil
    }

    return time.Time(*t), nil
}

func (t *Timestamp) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
    var tm time.Time

    if err := raw.Unmarshal(&tm); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *t = Timestamp(tm)

    return nil
}

func (t *Timestamp) String() string {
    return time.Time(*t).String()
}
```

and the article that goes with it: https://medium.com/coding-and-deploying-in-the-cloud/time-stamps-in-golang-abcaf581b72f

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
core/timestamp/timestamp.go:31: invalid indirect of t (type Timestamp)                                                                                                                                                     
core/timestamp/timestamp.go:35: invalid indirect of t (type Timestamp)
```

My relevant code looks like this:

```
import (
    "github.com/path/to/timestamp"
)

type User struct {
    Name        string
    Created_at  *timestamp.Timestamp  `bson:"created_at,omitempty" json:"created_at,omitempty"`
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Related question**
I can't see how to implement this package either. Do I create a new User model something like this?

```
u := User{Name: "Joe Bloggs", Created_at: timestamp.Timestamp(time.Now())}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has a typo. You can't dereference a non-pointer, so you need to make GetBSON a pointer receiver (or you could remove the indirects to `t`, since the value of `t` isn't changed by the method).

```
func (t *Timestamp) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
```

To set a `*Timestamp` value inline, you need to have a `*time.Time` to convert.

```
now := time.Now()
u := User{
    Name:      "Bob",
    CreatedAt: (*Timestamp)(&now),
}
```

Constructor and a helper functions like `New()` and `Now()` may come in handy for this as well.

Comment: That's what I thought but if you look at the revisions on GH then the author of the code made a change to this specifically. See the latest revision here: https://gist.github.com/bsphere/8369aca6dde3e7b4392c/revisions

Comment: Also do you know how I would implement this package when creating a new user?

Comment: The change makes no sense, since it's no longer valid Go. It's easy to verify by compiling it. I wouldn't put much faith in a random chunk of code off a blog post.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "implement this package when creating a new user".

Comment: I'm only testing it - what I mean by implement is how do create a new User with a `created_at` field with the timestamp as a value.

Comment: @tommyd456: Ah, I see. Added an example of created a `*Timestamp` inline.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to an indirection of something that is not a pointer variable.

```
var a int = 3         // a = 3
var A *int = &a       // A = 0x10436184
fmt.Println(*A == a)  // true, both equals 3
fmt.Println(*&a == a) // true, both equals 3
fmt.Println(*a)       // invalid indirect of a (type int)
```

**Thus, you can not reference the address of `a` with `*a`.**

Looking at where the error happens:

```
func (t Timestamp) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
        // t is a variable type Timestamp, not type *Timestamp (pointer)

        // so this is not possible at all, unless t is a pointer variable
        // and you're trying to dereference it to get the Timestamp value
        if time.Time(*t).IsZero() {
                return nil, nil
        }
        // so is this
        return time.Time(*t), nil
}
```

Comment: You cannot take the address of a function return (`&time.Now()`) nor can you take the address of a conversion (`&timestamp.Timestamp(time.Now())`). That line isn't valid Go.

Comment: @JimB you're right. I was too quick. That part removed thanks.